# Mongoose validation crashing app

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am attempting to create a user in mongo with mongoose. The user is created successfully but if I leave out a required parameter (to test validation), the whole app crashes with the message:

> No listeners detected, throwing. Consider adding an error listener to
>   your connection. ValidationError: User validation failed

I am using the express router for the register endpoint and code looks like so:

```
router.route('/register')
.post(function(req, res) {

    // Create new user
    var user   = new User();
    user.name  = req.body.name;
    user.email = req.body.email;

    user.save(function(err) {
        if (err) res.send(err);
        res.json({ message: 'User created!' });
    });
});
```

My very simple User schema is as follows:

```
// User schema
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
```

When I remove the required parameters it all works, but this is clearly not a solution.

How do I return proper validation messages when mongoose fails to create the user?

Answer (score 3):

You should do

```
var user = new User({ name: req.body.name, email: req.body.email });
user.save(function(err) { ... });
```

By doing this you supply the validated fields on user class creation, which should work.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I updated my syntax for creating the user to match yours but the error remains.

Comment: @nickspiel I just came across this error myself, too. Did you ever find a resolution to the issue?